# Send BiasFX guitar sound with laptop mic to Skype

Tags: electric-guitar

I'm on Windows 10, I have irigHD2 to interface my guitar to laptop.

I use Bias FX2 for effects with an ASIO driver provided with Irig.  It's all good.  I can get low latency audio from the Irig via amp out or headphones.

When I attend online guitar lessons I'd like to be able to do that with no amp to avoid disturbance. Wondered if I could do that by sending guitar after processing in Bias FX to Skype and merge my voice (from laptop mic) with it.

I've been doing a bit of googling and have installed the free version of Virtual Audio Cable 4.

I wondered what the best way to achieve that is.

Comment: We ought to have a canonical 'How can I route internal audio in my PC/Mac?' somewhere by now. Can anybody suggest a good one to work on? (btw,. for Mac it's 'Buy Loopback. Done.' but Win seems more troublesome)

Comment: Hmm… maybe https://vb-audio.com/Cable/ Seems to have Mac & Win versions. Never tried it myself.